# OWL Protege-5.0 how to set the range of Object Property as an external Ontolgoy class

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I am new to Protégé, and I am using Protégé 5.0 Beta.

I am building my own Ontology. One of my requirement is that every property should have an address. I found this Ontology for addresses
http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html#A

and I want to say that my `Property` class, has a relationship, lets call it `hasAddress`, and the range of that relationship is from `GeoNames` Ontology. I don't know the exact class of GeoNames that I am going to use, but even if I did, that wouldn't change anything in my question. Lets say that I am going to use class `A` from `GeoNames` Ontology.

#### My attemps to solve the problem

1. I have created a `class` on Protégé and I named it `Property`.
2. I have create an `Object Property` property and I named it `hasAddress`.

However, I didn't know how to tell Protégé that the range of that `hasAddress` is class `A` from `GeoNames` Ontology

#### Note 1:

I don't know if what I did is correct.

#### Note 2:

I don't know if `GenNames` is the best Ontology for addresses. Basically, I just need to set city name. However, I need to integrate my Ontology with an Address Ontology as a required task.

Answer (score 0):

heres some help if you still haven't figured out how to do this. You need to import the `GeoNames` ontology into your current. This can be achieved easily in protege using the following steps.

1) In protege on the Active Ontology tab there is a window called Imported Ontologies. Use this interface to import your other ontology into the current one (or the other way around, it really doesn't matter)
2) If you want to use a web resource select the option that says `import an ontology located in a document on the web` or use the `import ontology located on a specific file` option if you have downloaded the file in a .rdf extension.

3) Once you have succesfully imported said ontology, you will be able to use whatever class you want from the imported ontology in the current. Hope this helps :)